# I am getting following exception while installing - "Fail to get 'sdb'. (Cannot find repository. Please check your repository.)"

Tags: tizen, tizen-sdb

I am trying to install the Tizen SDK(32-bit) on Windows 7 32-bit OS. I am installing it by using SDK Image Installation process.

I followed the process given [at this web address](https://developer.tizen.org/downloads/sdk/installing-tizen-sdk).

But I am getting following exception while installing :

```
"Fail to get 'sdb'.it(Cannot find repository. Please check your repository.)".
```

Comment: What about if you do a normal install (i.e. not using an image file)?

Comment: What are you installing Tizen 2.3 or Tizen for wearable 1.0?